# Setting an Index Dynamically. Such that all possible inputs are divisible by the first

Tags: java, math

How do I use a set of numbers (all divisible by the first [15 in this case]) to get their respective indices, when each one doubles the last (15*2=30, 30*2=60...). I am looking for a way to do this mathematically, but it eludes me. I'd like one line of code (or a short method) to replace the below switch statement.

Consider the following code:

```
    //represents "h:mm"
    String[] values = new String[]{"0:15", "0:30", "1:00", "2:00"};
    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(values);
    comboBox.setEditable(false); //only values of values can be used

    ...

    switch(interval)
    {
        case 15:
            comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
            break;

        case 30:
            comboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
            break;

        case 60:
            comboBox.setSelectedIndex(2);
            break;

        case 120:
            comboBox.setSelectedIndex(3);
            break;
    }
```

In the above situation the `interval`will always be one of the 4 cases. My math brain has checked out for the night, and I can't think of how to use the numbers 15,30,60, and 120 to get the indices 0, 1, 2, and 3. I know there is a simple answer to this but it's late and it escapes me!

**Notes:**

-If you have a better name for this question please comment it, mine is terrible

-I know that I could (and have in the same class the above excerpt is from) use a Calendar instance and a ListCellRenderer to more easily accomplish this, but I've come across a situation like this before and can't remember how I solved it!

Comment: Mathematical answer 15/15 = 1 , 30/15 = 2, 60/15 = 4, 120/15 = 8 i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8 which is also 2^0 , 2^1, 2^2, 2^3 ( read '^' as to the power of) so you can do following log(interval/15, 2) that should give you 0, 1, 2, 3

Comment: My test yielded: 0, 1.386, 2.772, 4.1588. So the last is the only one that doesn't cast to the right integer index. Your below answer still holds true.

Comment: Math.log(15/15)/Math.log(2) should give you 0.0, Math.log(30/15)/Math.log(2) should give you 1.0, Math.log(60/15)/Math.log(2) should give you 2.0, Math.log(120/15)/Math.log(2) should give you 3.0 Trust me I tested it :)

Comment: Cast the whole expression (int)(Math.log(interval/15)/Math.log(2))

Comment: Well I made the mistake of reading log(interval/15, 2) as log(pow(interval/15, 2)), so that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single line replacement.

```
comboBox.setSelectedIndex((int)(Math.log(interval/15)/Math.log(2)));
```

Here is a sample program

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int interval: new int[]{15,30,60,120}){
            System.out.println((int)(Math.log(interval/15)/Math.log(2)));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thank you good sir. I knew logarithms were involved but ... I think it is time to stop for the night haha!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but is it something like this?

```
int base = 15;
for(int i = base, j = 0 ; i < base * 4 ; i *= 2, j++) {
   if(interval == i) {
       comboBox.setSelectedIndex(j);
       break;
   }
}
```

Note that I only used `base * 4` as loop condition based on your example, you could change that if you want.

You could also eliminate `j` by using below instead:

```
int base = 15;
for(int i = base ; i < base * 4 ; i *= 2) {
   if(interval == i) {
       comboBox.setSelectedIndex((i/base) - 1);
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: While your answer certainly works I used a switch to avoid using if and now want to do away with the switch. ^_^ I feel like there is an equation that defines what I'm getting at. such that `setSelectedIndex(base~interval)` where ~ is some math currently escaping my brain!